# Out of stock Products, Still showing in product count in categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I Hided out of stock items from the catalog in **Woocommerce > settings > inventory** and The out of stock products didn't appear in category page or any listing page and that is good so far .. However My product Categories widget is still counting my products including the out of stock products.

How can I also make the product Categories widget counting in stock products only ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to go to Woocommerce > Status > tools > Term counts ==> click on **"Recount terms"**

Comment: LoicTheAztec yes worked for me Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will be useful for someone.

Usually, the issue gets solved by Recounting the Terms. You will find that button by navigating to **WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Term Counts**.

But sometimes, the changes might not appear immediately for another category even after recounting the terms. In that case, you need to Recount the Terms again. Hope it will help.